# Should the [stofdoctrineextensions] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) is "just" a bundle, a bridge between DoctrineExtensions (package `gedmo/doctrine-extensions`) and Symfony.

Most (if not all) questions tagged with [stofdoctrineextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stofdoctrineextensions) are general questions related to Symfony (how to install/configure a package/bundle), or are questions about the extension itself. For that purpose, we already have [doctrine-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-extensions), and even [gedmo-loggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gedmo-loggable), and [gedmo-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gedmo-tree).

I think [stofdoctrineextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stofdoctrineextensions) should be burninated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination

Comment: The tag could use some cleaning up, but it certainly doesn't need to be burninated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While I am in no way a mod, I did a quick search for `[stofdoctrineextensions] -stofdoctrineextensions is:question -stof_doctrine_extensions -Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle -stof`, which gives 47 questions. The tag has 76 questions total. This indicates that most of the questions there don't involve `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle`

IMO, the tag is fairly small, and most of the questions are off-topic for it.
However, it isn't harming anything, nor does it fail the tests in the [Criteria for Burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), so I think it shouldn't be burninated.

Answer (score 2):

I am a Symfony developer and I have used the StofDoctrineExtensions (which is a bundle to integrate the Doctrine extensions by Gedmo into Symfony).

I read all 76 questions and they relate to this bundle and/or the extensions. From context it appears most of the questions about the Gedmo extensions are by people using the bundle, because of the configuration they ask about.

This tag is valid, but some grouping of it and related tags could be considered, keeping them as aliases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doctrine-extensions has the most questions but I wouldn't think to use it if I was asking a question about StofDoctrineExtensions. The Gedmo tags are too specific IMO.